# how to write SQL query in this situation

Tags: sql

I have table named "Attendance" which looks like this:

```
Sno  SecurityGroup  SecurityName  Designation   AttendanceStatus
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    JJ             Ram           officer       present
2    JJ             Raja          Guards        Present
3    JJ             Rani          LadyGuards    Present
4    JJ             Ramu          officer       present
```

I need the Output as count of number of securities present in each Designation as follows:

```
SecutityGroup Officer  Guards  LadyGuards
-----------------------------------------
JJ              2        1         1
```

Can someone please help me write a query to get this Output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried out using PIVOT in SQL, But i could not Get count value..
Following is Code i tried:

```
select SecurityGroup,Officer,Guards,LadyGuards from 
(select SecurityGroup,rDesignation from Attendance 
where SecurityGroup='jj') up
PIVOT (count(Designation) for Designation IN 
(Officer,Guards,LadyGuards)) as pvt
```

When i Execute this Query, I get
SecurityGroup,Officer,Guards,LadyGuards
JJ,0,0,0

Instead of,
SecurityGroup,Officer,Guards,LadyGuards
JJ,2,1,1

Answer (score 7):

```
select SecurityGroup,
    sum(case when Designation = 'officer' then 1 end) as Officer,
    sum(case when Designation = 'Guards' then 1 end) as Guards,
    sum(case when Designation = 'LadyGuards' then 1 end) as LadyGuards 
from Attendance
group by SecurityGroup
```

Alternately, if you are OK with having the information in rows instead, you can do:

```
select SecurityGroup, Designation, count(*) as Count
from Attendance
group by SecurityGroup, Designation
```

Obviously the second approach is preferred as it is less brittle, and will function if more `Designations` get added without any modification.

Comment: Why `SUM()` and not `COUNT()`?

Comment: @ypercube Either will work. `SUM` feels more clear to me when using a `CASE` like this.

Comment: But (with other data) it may show `NULL` instead of `0` - unless you make that `... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done with a PIVOT, depending on your database:

```
SELECT SecurityGroup, SUM([officer]) AS Officers, SUM([Guards]) AS Guards, SUM([LadyGuards]) AS LadyGuards
FROM Attendance
PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(Sno)
        FOR Designation IN ([officer], [Guards], [LadyGuards])
    ) as pvt
WHERE AttendanceStatus = 'Present'
GROUP BY SecurityGroup
```

If you want to have the column list generated dynamically based on whatever is in the table, it gets harder, but this avoids the needs for lots of subqueries.

Comment: These things (brackets?) `[]` are used in SQL-Server only. They are not proper SQL.

Comment: @ypercube: That is why I said "depending on your database." I wrote and tested the solution in SQL Server and posted it for reference. I don't usually use PIVOTs myself and just have it filed away under 'turn rows into columns', in case I ever need to do so. It looks like Oracle would use "'officer' as Officer" inside the IN, but SQL server doesn't seem to like that, so I just posted a simple solution that works in the environment I usually use. If it isn't helpful, I apologize.

Comment: No need to apologize. But it's usually good to add this info on your answer: "This works - and has been tested - in SQL-Server".

Comment: Even if the OP adds a "SomeExtremeDBMS" tag tomorrow, the future reader will still find this answer useful - and not get confused why you provided an SQL-Server solution that doesn't work for him.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here and will keep that in mind in the future. I actually did it all using a table variable so the whole thing could be run and tested in one script file, so I supposed I could have posted that as well, but I figured that might have just made the answer needlessly long. Anyway, thanks for the comments!

Comment: You can run/test scripts in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and then add a permalink in your answer - which you can edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select distinct SecurityGroup,
    select sum(*) from Attendance where designation = 'officer') as Officer,
    select sum(*) from Attendance where designation = 'Guards') as Guards,
    select sum(*) from Attendance where designation = 'LadyGuards') as LadyGuards    
from Attendance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub queries to get this accomplished:

```
SELECT
  SecurityGroup,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Attendance` WHERE `Designation` = "officer") AS `Officer`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Attendance` WHERE `Designation` = "Guards") AS `Guards`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Attendance` WHERE `Designation` = "LadyGuards") AS `LadyGuards`
FROM `Attendance`
WHERE `SecurityGroup` = "JJ"
```

I haven't actually tested this query, as I just wanted to share the concept with you.

Also please do note that is not the fastest way of accomplishing what you need done, but I believe it's the simplest way possible.

I hope this works for you.